# How can I access the textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList id="ItemsList"
      BorderColor="black"
      CellPadding="5"
      CellSpacing="5"
      RepeatDirection="Vertical"
      RepeatLayout="Table"
      RepeatColumns="3"
      runat="server">      

<ItemTemplate>

   <a href="#"  data-inline="true" data-role="button" 
        data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right">        
    <input type="text" id="txtTry" style="width: 20%" runat="server" 
        value="" data-mini="true"  
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StringValue") %>
   </a>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

how can I access the value of the text box of each button in the CS. How can I access it.This is not tough but I didn't use it yet.

Comment: `button` where's the button in your posted code ??

Comment: You say "this is not tough" but you have made no visible attempt to solve the problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: <a href="#"  data-inline="true" data-role="button" 
        data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right">  
is the button

Comment: Dan Puzey thats why asked you to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes change the html to Asp.net text box. Then you can get via method mentioned by oleksii

Even with input html text try the below sample  It should normally be done with

```
Request.Form["elementName"]
```

For example, if you have

`<input type="text" name="try" />` then you can use `Request.Form["try"]` to access its value.

Comment: Error Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 4):

You need to change HTML controls `<input>`
to the ASP.NET controls, for example:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtTry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Then later in your .cs file you can change the value of the textbox:

```
...
txtTry.Text = "foo";
...
```